# Trying to anchor a link in center of in-page scroller content

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

I am trying to link from www.membersolutions.com to a press release [here](http://www.membersolutions.com/ABOUT/news.html). All pages besides the homepage for the most part have that in-page scrollable content. Is there anyway I can link to a press release halfway down the page, I'm pretty sure you can't do it with straight HTML/CSS??

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the press release cannot even be scrolled at all since it precisely fits the visible panel. Anyway, in order to link halfway down a page, you would have to target an appropriate anchor. This would imply targeting a tag with a respective id attribute. With that, you could target page.html#anchor-name. As for custom scrolling, it would require some degree of JavaScript.